# Docker / Varnish / Hitch / Nginx / PHP : What is correct way to purge cache for specific page?

Tags: php, docker, nginx, docker-compose, varnish

I have setup simple php app via docker by using **hitch, varnish, nginx, php** and **mysql** containers.
To make **Hitch** work locally I've generated self-signed certificate via *mkcert* utility for *my.varnish.test* local domain that was added to **/etc/hosts**

So **https://my.varnish.test** works fine locally.

Here is github of the app: https://github.com/aposidelov/hitch-varnish-local-example

The app does following:

- **Listing page** (/index.php) where all rows from mysql table are shown.
- **Add form** (/user_add_form.php) that allows to add new row to mysql table.

I want **Listing page** to be cached via varnish and after **Add form** is submitted I want **Listing page** to be purged. For now */index.php* is cached by varnish but I have problems how to purge specific page after form is submitted.

**What is correct way to purge a cache?**

I've found approach by doing it using curl call with PURGE method.

`exec('curl -I -X PURGE https://my.varnish.test/index.php', $output, $retval);`

But as I use docker in my project it means that https://my.varnish.test is not available from nginx container (at least on my local machine). If I go inside my nginx container and try
`curl https://my.varnish.test/index.php` it doesn't see it, instead it's can see only `curl http://nginx_server/index.php`
but purge via `exec('curl -I -X PURGE http://nginx_server/index.php', $output, $retval);` doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Git repo has a [`default.vcl`](https://github.com/aposidelov/hitch-varnish-local-example/blob/master/docker/varnish/default.vcl) that has the necessary code in it to perform the purge.

However, the purge logic will not be reached because an earlier if-statement will result in an early exit.

Consider this code that is in your Git repo:

```
sub vcl_recv {
  if (req.method != "GET" && req.method != "HEAD") {
    return (pass);
  }
  if (req.method == "PURGE") {
    if (!client.ip ~ purge) {
      return (synth(405, client.ip + " is not allowed to send PURGE requests."));
    }
    return (purge);
  }
}
```

The `PURGE` request method will match the first if-statement (not a `GET` and not a `HEAD`) and will result in `return(pass);` being called.

Please put this if-statement after your purge logic and you'll be able to perform purges.

Another hurdle might be the ACL that is restricted to local IP addresses as you can see in the example below:

```
acl purge {
  "localhost";
  "127.0.0.1";
  "::1";
}
```

My advice is to look at the topology of your Docker setup and potentially add the IP address of the system that will execute the `PURGE` request. This could be an IP addressed issued by Docker.

Comment: Thank you for quick reply. I've made it work by fixing your updates + adding `my.varnish.test` as alias for varnish container. Now `exec('curl -I -X PURGE http://my.varnish.test', $output, $retval);` works fine. Before it was `exec('curl -I -X PURGE http://varnish', $output, $retval);`. I've pushed fresh update to the repo.